# Custom framework not loaded dyld: Library not loaded: @rpath/Custom.framework/

Tags: ios, frameworks, dyld, rpath

I have an app with several custom dynamic frameworks which means I am using iOS 8 as the SDK on Xcode 6.2. My Mac is on Yosemite. The frameworks have Swift sources and resources.

The app is distributed enterprise so I just create an IPA and distribute internally via a webpage where the user can download and install the app.

The app installs and runs on iPhone 5(iOS 8.1.2), iPod Touch(iOS 8.2) and simulators **BUT NOT** on iPhone 6(iOS 8.1.2). The error is always dyld: Library not loaded: @rpath/Custom.framework/. Whenever I remove and add the frameworks back to try to fix it another framework pops up as not loaded on the iPhone 6. (Why!!!)

The following were set:

- @executable_path/Frameworks
- Embedded Content Contains Swift code - Yes
- Frameworks in embedded binaries
- Embedded Frameworks
- Link Binary With Libraries

What is causing these issues and what can I do to make sure that the app runs consistently on all devices and iOS 8 versions.

Most of the solutions I find are trial and error suggestions.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I didn't stop figuring out the cause of the issue until I read about architectures. So it prompted me to build the frameworks while an iPhone 6 is connected. I created a project with all the defaults. Added a couple of frameworks including Alamofire. Built them while iPhone 6 connected. Generated an archive and deployed and installed OTA. When the app was installed it ran without issues.

I tried to confirm it by building against my iPod(MD717ZP/A). I'm not sure if this was 5th Gen. First I emptied the derived data folder, Cleaned all projects including the frameworks. Built and deployed the app. Installed it on the iPod it was running. I installed it on the iPhone 6 and it crashed instantly.

I tried the same process over and over again. Built against iPhone 6 then iPod then installed on both. The results just confirmed that I need to have it built on iPhone 6 so the app would run on that device and lower.

Remember I ONLY did add the frameworks to "Embedded Binaries" (Target > General > Embedded Binaries) then built on iPhone 6 to make it work. This could mean you need to have the latest device if you want it running on all devices due to some architecture requirements.

**Update:**
In addition to the knowledge above you may want to check the "**Build Active Architecture Only**" section in the **Build Settings** tab. It means it will build based on the connected hardware if set to YES else it will build for the architectures you support like Valid Architectures.

Comment: A thousand up votes bro, if I can. This is the answer, "Remember I ONLY did add the frameworks to "Embedded Binaries" (Target > General > Embedded Binaries)"

Comment: This is the freaking best answer ever. Thank you!

Comment: Thx, saved me tons of time

Answer (score 0):

Check the Linking section in the Build Settings tab, following item may not been set:

```
Runpath Search Paths = @executable_path/Frameworks
```

- This fixed an error for me:

  ```
  dyld: library not loaded: @rpath/CorePlot.framework/CorePlot
  reason: image not found
  ```

Answer (score 0):

I had same issue with xcode 10 with Mojave & I am using Cocoa pods, here are my solution :

1. Make sure your target->build settings->iOS Deployment Target is set to the latest IOS.
2. In Pod file, remove "inherit! :search_paths" for the test UI target. For Eg.

> ```
> Existing pod file :
>
>     target 'MyApp' do
>         pod 'oAuthorize'
>         target 'MyUITest1' do
>             inherit! :search_paths
>         end
>         target 'MyFunctionalTest' do
>             inherit! :search_paths
>         end
>     end
>     Remove "inherit! :search_paths" for all sub-targets. 
>
>     target 'MyApplication' do
>         pod 'oAuthorize'
>         target 'MyUITest1' do
>         end
>         target 'MyFunctionalTest' do
>         end
>     end
> ```